# How to add form dynamically in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my application, I have JSPs: demo1.jsp, demo2.jsp

When the user clicks "Add" button (this is in demo1.jsp) then demo2.jsp should appear in the proper position.

If form is in the same JSP/HTML there is no problem. Using the form id we can create using jQuery.

But here we are handling two JSPs, so how to do this?

**demo1.jsp**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="question" id="que3">
         <span class="heading">Form Details</span> 
         <span class="button2 white" >Add</span>
     </div>
    <div class="answer">
        <jsp:include page="demo2.jsp">
            <jsp:param value="counter_crt" name="counter_crt" />
        </jsp:include>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

How do we write a jQuery function to create demo2.jsp dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX.

```
$("#addbutton").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "demo2.jsp",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#answer").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing will happen.. i'm checking using alert boxes but their is no alert show.

Comment: where are you using the alert boxes? debug using firebug or chrome dev tools. check whether ajax is called or not.